# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException on ArrayList in multi thread

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

Hi have defined two thread here EvenThread1 & OddThread2. The EvenThread1 is printing even number from the ArrayList and corresponding removing value from the list. Same OddThread2 is also printing odd number from the same ArrayList and corresponding removing value from the list.
The problem is that when I am executing 2 or 3 times java.util.ConcurrentModificationException is coming on console.
Even I am removing the value from the list with valid check.

```
if (j.intValue() >= 0)
{
    it.remove();
}
```

I know why it is coming but I am not able to resolve in this program.
Could you please suggest me how to resolve this exception in the following program with explanations?

```
 package MultiThreading;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Eg2
    {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        new EvenThread1();
        new OddThread2();

        }
    }

    class EvenThread1 implements Runnable
    {

        List<Integer> list = Services1.getNum();

        EvenThread1()
        {
        Thread th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
        Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            Integer j = (Integer) it.next();
            int a = j % 2;
            if (a == 0)
            {
            System.out.println("Even: " + j.intValue());
            if (j.intValue() >= 0)
            {
                it.remove();
                System.out.println("List Data=" + list);
            }

            }

        }

        }

    }

    class OddThread2 implements Runnable
    {

        List<Integer> list = Services1.getNum();

        OddThread2()
        {
        Thread th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
        Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            Integer j = (Integer) it.next();
            int a = j % 2;
            if (a != 0)
            {
            System.out.println("Odd: " + j.intValue());
            if (j.intValue() >= 0)
            {
                it.remove();
                System.out.println("List Data=" + list);
            }

            }

        }

        }

    }

    abstract class Services1
    {

        static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        static
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            list.add(i);
        }
        }

        static public List<Integer> getNum()
        {
        return list;
        }

    }
```

Comment: There is literally no way to do this in parallel. You need to synchronize access to the list, get an iterator and remove the even numbers; then synchronize access to the list, get an iterator and remove the odd numbers (or the other way round). There is no point in doing this in two threads, since each of the threads requires exclusive access to the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
    static List<Integer> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

You need to synchronise your **list** like the above code, because it will be concurrency invocation.

Comment: Notice that he also need to synchronize when using an iterator over the list, as per javadoc of `synchronizedList`

Comment: Hi, you are almost ok as a java programmatic concept, but even it is not working, it saying same exception still. But I got the solution we have to lock the list object in each thread by synchronization block. Example: synchronized(list){.....} but you are also correct that should also work, but here is not working, I don't not why?

Answer (score 0):

`ConcurrentLinkedDeque` is a list-like data structure that supports concurrent operations. And it can return a `Spliterator` that reports `Spliterator.CONCURRENT`. That's a good start. But to make a solution work even with these you'd need to be able to create two `Spliterator`s, one for evens and the other for odds, and they'd have to be able to keep track of their respective elements somehow. Generalization: return a `Set` of `Spliterator` given something that implements a partitioning strategy, and make sure *all* of them keep track of their own elements.

Strictly speaking, that's not impossible. But you don't get it out of the box. You'll have to do some interesting (i.e. tricky and error-prone) coding to make such a thing happen.

Have fun, and put it up on `github` or somewhere similar when you have it done. :-)